# What do the stormtroopers describe as obsolete in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

At the beginning of the beach part of Rogue One, two stormtroopers are discussing something that they say is being rendered obsolete, followed by 'It was about time'.

It sounded like AT18, which is not a thing. It cannot be an AT-TE, as in Star Wars: Rebels it is obsolete already. What was it?

Comment: While watching it, I assumed that whatever they said was the class of droid that includes K-2S0. From the answers it seems it probably isn't, but that would make sense in the context of the film.

Comment: Not precisely related, but the Jedi Knight games have similar stormtrooper banter if you stop and listen to them without them noticing you sometimes. I find it an amusing and clever way to make a scene feel more natural, presumably they talk about something all the time, right?

Comment: Given the word-of-god confirmation from LucasFilm in my answer, I'm a little surprised that your acceptance is still sitting with the (now-revealed-to-be) incorrect answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's referring to the T-16 skyhopper. It's the airship Luke owns in episode four. When they say that there is a replacement they specifically say the T-15. In *A New Hope* you also see Luke playing with a model of it.
[image: T-16]

Comment: This, to me, fits most closely with what I remember. I thought they said 'E-15' and were talking about their rifles, but turns out I was thinking of E-11s.

Comment: Is it? I mean, Luke "used to bullseye womp rats in [his] T-16 back home, they're not much bigger than two meters. "

Comment: @Axelrod you're right, now that I think of it. Maybe the stormtroopers are avid womp rat bullseyers

Comment: @AdamPalaniuk It could be that the company that produced the T-16 could make it obsolete by no longer supporting it since he T-16 has permeated markets everywhere, even on backwater parents. There has been no mention of T-15s anywhere else, but with the way that line was phrased, and the fact that the T-16 does exist is why I assumed that.

Comment: @CBredlow "The company that produced the T-16" was Incom, manufacturer of the X-Wing. Depending on what's still canon, most of that company defected to the Alliance well before this point, some out of principle, the rest out of gratitude for being rescued by the Alliance after being sent to labor camps by the Empire. It seems unlikely that obsoleting a craft seemingly completely out of circulation well before this point would be high on its list of priorities.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen of this *supposed* jury, this answer does not make sense! Why would the *successor* to the T-16 be named the T-15? Especially if the T-17 was then [released during The Force Awakens timeframe](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-17/)? Or, if the T-16 was the successor to this "T-15", how would backwater farmboy Luke Skywalker already own the **newest model** to bullseye Wamp Rats in his T-16 back home?

Comment: @pkamb You're confusing what obsoleting a product means.  It just means that they are no longer working on producing any more of this craft, or offering support for it.  It's similar to how different smartphones work, company a makes product 1, and a few months later releases 2.  Both are available, and are recieving updates/support. After a while the company can say "Hey, we're no longer supporting 1, with focus on 2, and development of 3".

Comment: It is a nod to the fans from the new generation of film makers. In _A New Hope_ , 2 stormtroopers in the Death Star are discussing the "new T-16". In _The Force Awakens_ , we hear First Order Stormtroopers talk about "the new T-17". And to complete the circle, we hear stormtroopers mentioning "the old T-15" in _Rogue One_ .

Comment: The closed captioning says "T-15"

Comment: The line (according to [Journey to Star Wars the Force Awakens - Stormtroopers: Beyond the Armor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34150818-stormtroopers)) **should have read VT-15, not T-15**) and apparently no-one noticed.

Answer (score 8):

I believe they're discussing the [VT-16](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/VT-16). This is the same topic the Stormtroopers in A New Hope discuss while Obi-Wan Kenobi is disabling the tractor beam.

Curiously the Wookieepedia article suggests this is a droid seen in Return of the Jedi. Personally I'd dispute that as it seems an odd thing for Stormtroopers to discuss, and I'd assume that VT-16 and BT-16 are different things. But the link above does quote the conversation from A New Hope.

EDIT: After a second viewing they definitely say T-15. I now believe the quote on Wookieepedia is misplaced, and that those Stormtroopers are actually discussing the T-16, not VT-16.

Answer (score 4):

This line in Rogue One was apparently a mis-quote by the voice actors that somehow made it into the completed film. They were trying to back-reference the line from A New Hope complaining about the [famously obsolete VT-16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hs9BRRVFGMw&feature=youtu.be&t=1m45s) (an item that has [no canon existence](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleImplements) other than to be complained about).

> *“Without saying a word, without being called upon, and without even
> looking at each other, Sam and I stood up from our chairs and walked
> up to the array of microphones in front of the movie screen. Matthew
> said, ‘Okay, we need some kind of stormtrooper dialogue here,
> guys . . . oh, looks like you’re ready, let’s go for it.’*
>
> *“Sam spoke first, and I spoke second, delivering the line about T-15s
> being made obsolete. He reacted in that great trooper monotone, and
> then we both performed a vocal for being taken down by rebels. The
> room laughed. We did a second take, and that was it. The whole thing
> went down in less than two minutes.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Stormtroopers: Beyond the Armor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34150818-stormtroopers)</sup></sub>

and

> [The picture above shows a] frame of two stormtroopers having a conversation about the obsolete T-15. The exchange was intended to set up the conversation overheard during A New Hope regarding the new VT-16. However, the Rogue One conversation identifies the previous model as a T-15, incorrectly calling out the letters as that would link the two references.
>
> <sub><sup>[Stormtroopers: Beyond the Armor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34150818-stormtroopers)</sup></sub>

We can assume that the VT-15 is also a *non-object that troopers complain about periodically* (although I've heard that the T-17 is going to be a vast improvement).

Answer (score 2):

It's a nod to A New Hope, "You seen that new VT-16?"
"Yeah, some of the other guys were telling me about it. They say it's… it's quite a thing to see…"
―KE-829 and his partner aboard the first Death Star
The BT-16 perimeter droid, also known as the VT-16, was a bulbous, spider-like droid.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought they said "C-15"; I assumed it had something to do with a Clone army and was a passing reference to the imperial army weaning itself off of clone troopers.

Comment: That would have been a really cool easter-egg. Except that they were talking about a single thing and not a group. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a reference to the non canon characters, Tag and Bink! It also could be a reference to episode 4, when Tag and Bink are talking about the BT-16.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning?

Answer (score -2):

They are talking about the [T-15 Snub Rifle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-15_snub_rifle) that stormtroopers carry.

Comment: Can you back this up?

Comment: This needs to cite a source. Wookieepedia says the [T-15](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-15_snub_rifle) is Legends only. Granted, *Rogue One* just barely came out but the Wookieepedia editors have been actively updating pages related to the movie.